# get live data from national stock exchange

Tags: equities

http://billing.finance.yahoo.com/realtime_quotes/signup?.src=quote&.refer=quote

Can i get real time data(from NSE india) using Yahoo finance API after subscribing to their service ?

Comment: Frankly you could take the time to format, at least slightly, your question.

Comment: The OP seems to have gotten an answer on [money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/10859/4557).  That community seems to be more tolerant of these sorts of questions.  I post this here in the hopes that future posters will go directly to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it supports 3 exchanges: NYSE, NASDAQ, and AMEX.